# How to insert data to a table then use the last id saved to insert to a different table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

```
public function postBomCopy(Request $request){ 

   $bom_id = $request->bom_id;       

   $total  = $request->total_cost;

   //insert the bom name first to get the new bom_id
   $bom = new Bom();
   $bom->cost=20;
   $bom->name=$request->bom;        
   $bom->save();        

    //get the new BOM DETAILS
   $new_bom_id = Bom::where('name', $bom->name)->orderBy('id', "DESC")
    ->first();        
   $n_bom_d = $new_bom_id->id; 

   foreach ($request->item as $key=> $v) { 
    $bom_new_id = new Bom_list();
    $bom_new_id ->bom_id = $n_bom_d;

    $data = array(
                 'item_id' => $request->item[$key],
                 'qty' => $request->item[$key],
                 'unit_cost' => $request->item[$key],
                 'total_cost' => $request->item[$key]
             );

   $bom_copy = $bom->bomList()->save($data); 
  } 


 Session()->flash('success','BOM successfully copied');
 return redirect()->back();
}
```

this is the error I get.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
>   Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\PrimeCartonInventory\app\Http\Controllers\UsersController.php on line 663

Comment: bomList() is the relationship name

Answer (score 1):

To solve the given error, you should pass eloquent object of Bom_list.

correct way: $bom_copy = $bom->bomList()->save(new Bom_list($data));

**And you will get last id when save() method is called**

```
//insert the bom name first to get the new bom_id
   $bom = new Bom();
   $bom->cost=20;
   $bom->name=$request->bom;        
   $bom->save();
   dd($bom->id); // will get the id of bom object u inserted in db
```

**Another good way can be by storing all data in collection and then insert in db at one time.**

```
   $bom = new Bom();
   $bom->cost=20;
   $bom->name=$request->bom;        
   $bom->save();        

   $bom_list_collection = collect();

   foreach ($request->item as $key=> $v) { 
     $data = array(
                 'bom_id' => $bom->id,
                 'item_id' => $request->item[$key],
                 'qty' => $request->item[$key],
                 'unit_cost' => $request->item[$key],
                 'total_cost' => $request->item[$key]
             );
     $bom_list_collection ->push(new Bom_list($data));
   } 
   $bom_copy = $bom->bomList()->saveMany($data);
```

Refere the link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: when I remove this " 'bom_id' => $bom->id, " part of the code. It works but when I insert it throws an error

Comment: (bom_id) column should be present in bom_list table if using relation. or if u have given other name instead of bom_id, use that inseat of bom_id.

Comment: Edit: $bom_copy = $bom->bomList()->saveMany($bom_list_collection);

Answer (score 0):

Last insert id of bom table.

```
$n_bom_d = $bom->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the array as string and try to save

```
foreach ($request->item as $key=> $v) { 
    $bom_new_id = new Bom_list();
    $bom_new_id ->bom_id = $n_bom_d;

    $data = array(
                 'item_id' => $request->item[$key],
                 'qty' => $request->item[$key],
                 'unit_cost' => $request->item[$key],
                 'total_cost' => $request->item[$key]
             );

   $data_new=json_encode($data);
   $bom_new_id->bom_list=$data_new;
   $bom_copy = $bom_new_id->save(); 
  }
```

Comment: where is this "bom_list" from on this line   $bom_new_id->bom_list=$data_new ?

Comment: you have to give the column name you are going to save the data array instead of bom_list, i have just assigned the variable name